# drawRect is not refreshing the screen

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have this code in my drawRect method

```
float aValue = .0167f;
float fValue = 20;
for(int i=1; i<=6; i++)
        {

            CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", fValue, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
            CGContextSetCharacterSpacing(context, 0);
            CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);

            NSString *hString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",i];


            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 1, 1, aValue);
            CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, i*25, i*16, [hString UTF8String], [hString length]);
            aValue += 0.167;
            fValue += 1;

        }
```

I am calling a method using NSTimer like this

```
staticTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(refreshUIView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

here is the refreshUIView

```
-(void)refreshUIView
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Problem is that drawRect is not clearing the screen, its just over writing what have been written last time on screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this early in `drawRect:` once you get the context.

```
CGContextClearRect( context , [self bounds] );
```

Or call `[super drawRect:];` if `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` is set.

Comment: just found that setting Opaque: NO to that UIView will refresh drawRect automatically.